# Sampling a function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

just for fun i was trying to make 100 samples of this function:
S1t = 3sin(ωt + /3) knowing that f is 10 Hz, T is 1/f, ω = 2/T. So, i've never done this kind of things but i've written some code:

```
import time
import math


f = 1000000
T = 1/f
omega = 360/T
i = []

for t in range(100):

    S1t = 3*math.sin((omega*t)+60)
    i = [S1t]
    print(i[t])
```

When i run this code i get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/wave_analyzer.py", line 25, in 
    print(i[t])
IndexError: list index out of range

Apart from that, i think that there is something wrong in the logic of this code, so i was guessing how you would do that. Thank you for your attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to `append` the `S1t` to your list use:

```
import time
import math


f = 1000000
T = 1/f
omega = 6.28/T
i = []

for t in range(100):

    S1t = 3*math.sin((omega*t)+60)
    i.append(S1t)
    print(i[t])
```

In your version, `i` was always being recreated as a single element list.

If you want to plot it, use:

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = 1000000
T = 1/f
omega = 6.28/T
i = [3*math.sin((omega*t)+60) for t in range(100)]    

plt.plot(i)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you, tha worked pretty fine. If you had to make this code how would you do that? And do you know any way to draw a graph with all the samples on it? Thanks!

Comment: Wait, whenever i run the plotting code it doesn't return anything, it just runs it and i stops